# Remove Properties and Personal Information - Batch mode or app

Tags: windows, metadata

I am trying to remove all the properties\personal information from a set of media files in a bunch of different folders. So far the only way I have found is by clicking into each folder, selecting all files and doing the process manually like [this](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=198).

Does anyone know of any free apps, or scripts that can do this across multiple file locations?

Comment: What sorts of media files are you dealing with?

Comment: Music primarily, but some video.

Comment: I have to ask...Whats in the properties that you **MUST** delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need separate tools for different types of files, to gain the control you seek.

To batch remove image EXIF metadata, use [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) ([and more here](http://dptnt.com/2007/09/how-to-remove-exif-data-from-photos-with-free-tools/))

To batch remove MP3 metadata, use [The GodFather](http://users.otenet.gr/~dtou20/). Although I'm not too sure why you'd want to remove your ID3 tags?

MP4's can contain anything from lyrics to album art, but I'm sure it won't contain any personal info, unless you put it in there specifically.

**Update**: To blank with TGF, scan the songs you want to clear, onthe Tag tab (green) check all the fields to blank (red) and click the Apply button, then click Update.

[image]

Comment: The Godfather did not work, however, your comment on ID3 tags lead me to search and find ID3 killer (and some fix apps too). Even though you didn't find exactly what I was looking for you lead me down the right path, this you win the bounty, thanks!

Comment: Sorry to hear TGF didn't work for you, it's amazing when you get to know it :)

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Music Library. Click the dropdown labeled "Arrange By" at the upper right. Choose "arrange by song".

[image]

You will now have a listing of every song in your music library. Select all those you wish to remove the properties from; then right-click and choose properties. Go to the details tab and click "remove personal info". Voila!

[image]

Make sure to change your "view" setting back to "folder" when you're done, otherwise you'll have a hard time sorting through all your music.

Comment: I get 'there are no details in common' when doing this.

Comment: Make sure that you select only media files of the same type when you do this. So, you would have to do all of the mp3 files together, all of the .avi files at the same time, etc. You can't just select every single file; that won't work. I tested it with a selection of mp3's though and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For JPEG images, my favourite tool is EXIFCleaner by Superutils.

> [ExifCleaner](http://www.superutils.com/products/exifcleaner/) is a batch Windows utility
>   that lets you to remove individual
>   Exif tags or to strip Exif data
>   entirely. This protects your privacy,
>   helps you to hide unneeded or
>   sometimes sensitive information --
>   about the image, photographer and
>   location.

It's free for 30 days, but works like a charm even after the trial period ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it just with Windows Explorer by running a search which produces all the files you want to scrub, selecting all and using the properties dialog as you have been doing.

Comment: What like a *.mp3 search?

Comment: This does not show the music file properties.

Comment: I don't have Vista/7 to try it out. What exactly goes wrong? Hopefully you are not selecting folders too?

Answer (score -1):

This article has your answer :

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-remove-the-metadata-from-your-photos-windows-only/