# How to stop auto filling metadata by window and other software like photoshop

Tags: windows-7, window

When I work on graphic (Photo's) all metadata Time,date etc automatically noted down by computer software, Is it is possible to stop it? I do not want any information regarding this on my finished work ( photoshop etc)

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be dealt with program-by-program, since it's up to the individual programs to deal with their data's metadata, not (just) the OS. Check the options of each program you use and see if you can disable their metadata handling (either reading, or writing, or both) for their data files.

To deal with your actual problem (not having metadata in final product), why not just remove them all when done?  It can easily be done in bulk in Windows 7, as seen in these other SU questions:

- [How to remove the meta data of all files within a folder and it's sub folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/307606/how-to-remove-the-meta-data-of-all-files-within-a-folder-and-its-sub-folders)
- [Remove Properties and Personal Information - Batch mode or app](https://superuser.com/questions/129911/remove-properties-and-personal-information-batch-mode-or-app)
- [How to remove title and other metadata from video files?](https://superuser.com/questions/767544/how-to-remove-title-and-other-metadata-from-video-files)